# TPL Tasks, Threads, etc

Tags: multithreading, task, threadpool, task-parallel-library

Could someone clear up to me how these things correlate:

Task
Thread
ThreadPool's thread
Paraller.For/ForEach/Invoke

I.e. when I create a Task and run it, where does it get a thread to execute on? And when I call Parallel.* what is really going on under the covers?

Any links to articles, blogposts, etc are also very welcomed!

Comment: Excellent book, Concurrent Programming on Windows, good read, at least the half I've done so far ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal state of a system is to have 1 actively running thread per CPU core.  By defining work in more general terms of "tasks", the TPL can dynamically decide how many threads to use and which tasks to do on each one in order to come closest to achieving that ideal state.  These are decisions that are almost always best made dynamically at runtime because when writing the code you can't know for sure how many CPU cores will be available to your application, how busy they are with other work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Thread:**  is a real OS thread, has handle and ID.

**ThreadPool:**  is a collection of already-created OS Threads.  These threads are owned/maintained by the runtime, and your code is only allowed to "borrow" them for a while, you can only do work short-termed work in these threads, and you can't modify any thread state, nor delete these threads.

Best guesses on these two:

**Task:**  might get run on a pre-created thread in the thread pool, or might get run as part of user-mode scheduling, this is all depending on what the runtime thinks is best.  Another guess:  with TPL, the user-mode scheduling is NOT based on OS Fibers, but is its own complete (and working) implementation).

**Parallel.For:**  actually, no clue how this is implemented.  The runtime might create new threads to do the parallel bits, or much more likely use the thread pool's threads for the parallelism.